# Error in JSONParser class in BufferedReader

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am  trying to save my phone contacts to online Mysql database. Everything works fine but it returns null json object in JSONParser class. I debug the application and what I found is that there might be some problem in BufferedReader. It throws an exception because php code is unable to create row through JSON.

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    StringBuilder sb;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                Log.d("Hope","Hope 1");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                Log.d("Hope","Hope 2");
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                Log.d("Hope","Hope 3");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                Log.d("Hope","Hope 4");
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                Log.d("Hope","Hope 5");
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.d("ex1","ex1 "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("ex1","ex2 "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ex1","ex3 "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            //here is line which is giving some problem 
            //which I don't know and giving null JSONObject

            Log.d("Hope","Hope 6");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            Log.d("Hope","Hope 7");
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            Log.d("Hope","Hope 8");
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            //printed json value  "json{"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred"
            Log.d("eee","json"+ json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + json);
        }

        char[] chars = json.toCharArray();
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        if(chars[0] != 'D'){
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
                Log.d("null","null");
        }

    return jObj;        
    }
}
```

**MY log is given below**

```
02-20 02:39:03.810: D/ex1(3282): ex3 java.net.UnknownHostException: amiranzur.com
  02-20 02:39:03.810: D/Hope(3282): Hope 6
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/Buffer Error(3282): Error converting result 
02-20 02:39:03.810: W/dalvikvm(3282): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d578)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at com.example.android.contactslist.ui.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:104)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at com.example.android.contactslist.ui.SavingContacts$LoadSavingInDatabase.doInBackground(SavingContacts.java:55)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at com.example.android.contactslist.ui.SavingContacts$LoadSavingInDatabase.doInBackground(SavingContacts.java:1)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-20 02:39:03.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306
```

AND MY PHP CODE IS:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['phone'])&& isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crm(id, name, phone, email) VALUES('$id', '$name', '$phone', '$email')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: what is error in this.? log cat does not show any error.

Comment: application is working correctely but I json object  return null, so I am failed to save phone contacts to mysql database.

Comment: debug and check did you get true in this if condition `if(chars[0] != 'D')` or not.?

Comment: It got true and has a character of "{"message":"Oops! An error occurred.","success":0} in this

Comment: i dont think it is firing error please debug and check if it is firing exception please show exception. else code is very fine.

Comment: Now with the same code I am getting different error I am editing the logcat please hava look, I am tired to figure it out please help me